# jQuery JSON Data Does Not Populate Or Display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am having problem with my application. I hope some of you can assist me on this.

Here is my html, I need to fill the p element with id console and listview with id slots with the JSON data.

```
    <!-- **** SESSIONS PAGE **** -->

<div data-role="page" id="sessions">

  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Sessions</h1>
    <a href='javascript:refresh();' data-icon="refresh" id="refresh" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn-left" data-iconpos="notext"></a> 
  </div>

  <div data-role="content">
    <p id="console"></p>
    <ul data-role="list-view" data-inset="true" id="slots">
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="toolbar">
    <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#home" data-icon="home" data-transition="fade">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="ui-btn-active" href="#sessions" data-icon="grid" data-transition="fade">Sessions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#where" data-icon="info" data-transition="fade">Where</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about" data-icon="star" data-transition="fade">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="feedback.html" data-ajax="false" data-icon="plus" data-rel="dialog">Feedback</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- **** SESSION'S DETAILS PAGE **** -->

<div data-role="page" id="details" data-add-back-btn="true">

  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Session detail</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content">
    <div id="sessionInfo"> </div>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="toolbar">
    <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#home" data-icon="home" data-transition="fade">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sessions" data-icon="grid" data-transition="fade">Sessions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#where" data-icon="info" data-transition="fade">Where</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about" data-icon="star" data-transition="fade">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="feedback.html" data-ajax="false" data-icon="plus" data-rel="dialog">Feedback</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Here is my script (index.js) to populate session list and session details with JSON data.

```
var data;

$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {

    if (navigator.platform=="iPhone" || navigator.platform=="iPad" ||
        navigator.platform=="iPod" || navigator.platform=="iPad" ||
        navigator.platform=="iPhone Simulator" ) {

        // It's an iOS device, we check if we are in chrome-less mode
        if (!navigator.standalone) {
            showIOSInvitation();
        }
    }

    /* We capture the sessions page load to check dynamic session data */
    $("#sessions").live("pageshow", function() {

        if (window.localStorage!=undefined) {
            // HTML5 Local Storage is available
            if (window.localStorage.getItem("data")!=undefined &&
                       window.localStorage.getItem("data")!=null) {
                // We first load the offline stored session information while checking updates
                showSessions(window.localStorage.getItem("data"));  
                $("#console").html("Checking data update");
            } else {
                // There is no local storage cache
                $("#console").html("Downloading session data...");
            }
        } else {
            // No HTML5 Local Storage, downloading JSON every time
            $("#console").html("Downloading session data...");
        }       

        loadSessionsAjax(); 
    });

});

function showIOSInvitation() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // We hide the saving information until the whole webapp is downloaded
        $("#install").hide();
        // We open the iOS instructions for adding to the homepage
        $.mobile.changePage($("#ios"), {transition: "slideup", changeHash: false});
    }, 100);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#consoleInstall").html("Application downloaded");
            $("#install").show();
    }, 1000)

    // We capture HTML5 Application Cache events to provide useful information
    if (window.applicationCache!=undefined) {
        window.applicationCache.addEventListener('checking', function() {
            $("#consoleInstall").html("Checking version");
        });

        window.applicationCache.addEventListener('downloading', function() {
            $("#consoleInstall").html("Downloading applicaiton. Please wait...");
        });

        window.applicationCache.addEventListener('cached', function() {
            $("#consoleInstall").html("Application downloaded");
            $("#install").show();
        });

        window.applicationCache.addEventListener('updateready', function() {
            $("#consoleInstall").html("Application downloaded");
            $("#install").show();
        });
        window.applicationCache.addEventListener('noupdate', function() {
            $("#consoleInstall").html("Application downloaded");
            $("#install").show();
        });
        window.applicationCache.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
            $("#consoleInstall").html("There was an error downloading this app");                                                       
        }); 
        window.applicationCache.addEventListener('obsolete', function(e) {
            $("#consoleInstall").html("There was an error downloading this app");                                                       
        });                 
    } 

}

function loadSessionsAjax() {
    // We bring the JSON as text so it's easy to store in Local Storage
    $.ajax(/*"http://www.mobilexweb.com/congress/*/"sessions.json", {
        complete: function(xhr) {
            if (window.localStorage!=undefined) {
                if (window.localStorage.getItem("data")!=undefined && window.localStorage.getItem("data")!=null) {
                    if (xhr.responseText==window.localStorage.getItem("data")) {
                        // The new session downloaded is the same as the one in screen
                        $("#console").html("Schedule is updated");                      
                    } else {
                        // There is an update on the session data
                        if (confirm("There is an update in the schedule available, do you want to load it now?")) {
                            $("#console").html("Schedule is updated");  
                            showSessions(xhr.responseText); 
                        } else {
                            $("#console").html("Schedule will be updated later");                                       
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // Local Storage is available but no previous cache found
                    $("#console").html("Schedule is updated");  
                    showSessions(xhr.responseText); 
                }
            } else {
                // No Local Storage, show the info without saving
                $("#console").html("Schedule is updated");  
                showSessions(xhr.responseText);                         
            }
        },
        dataType: 'text',
        error: function() {
            $("#console").html("Schedule update could not be downloaded");  
        }
    });
}


var isFirstLoad = true;

function showSessions(string) {
    if (window.JSON!=undefined) {
        data = JSON.parse(string);  
    } else {
        data = eval("(" + string + ")");    
    }   
    if (window.localStorage!=undefined) {
        // Save the new data as string
        window.localStorage.setItem("data", string);
    }

    $("#slots").html("");

    var html = "";
    for (var i=0; i<data.slots.length; i++) {

        if (data.slots[i].message!=null) {
            // This is an special slot, so we create a divider
            html += "<li data-role='list-divider' data-groupingtheme='e'>" + data.slots[i].time + ": " + data.slots[i].message  + "</li>";                  
        } else {
            // This is a normal slot with sessions
            html += "<li><a href='javascript:showDetails(" + i + ")'>Sessions of " + data.slots[i].time + "</a></li>";
        }
    }

    $("#slots").html(html);

    if (isFirstLoad) {
        $("#slots").listview();
        isFirstLoad = false;
    } else {
        $("#slots").listview('refresh');                
    }

}

function showDetails(index) {           
    $("#details h1").html("Sessions of " + data.slots[index].time);
    var html = ""
    for (var i=0; i<data.sessions.length; i++) {
        if (data.sessions[i].timeId==data.slots[index].id) {
            // We create one collapsible component per session
            html += "<div data-role='collapsible'>";
            html += "<h3>" + data.sessions[i].title + "</h3>";
            html +=" <h3>" + data.sessions[i].room + "</h3>";
            html += "<h4>Speaker/s: " + data.sessions[i].speaker;
            html += "</h4>";
            html += "<p>" + data.sessions[i].description + "</p>";  
            html += "</div>";
        }
    }
    // We provide the information to the details page
    $("#sessionInfo").html(html);
    $("#sessionInfo div").collapsible();

    // We change to the details page
    $.mobile.changePage($("#details"));
}

function refresh() {
    $("#console").html("Verifying...");
    loadSessionsAjax();
}

function openWithoutInstallation() {
    // We remove the dialog-like iOS installation page
    $.mobile.changePage($("#home"), {transition:"slideup", reverse:true});  
}
```

Here is my JSON data (sessions.json)

```
   { 
  "slots": 
   [
     { "id": 1, "time": "09:00", "message": "Opening" },     
     { "id": 2, "time": "09:20"},      
     { "id": 3, "time": "10:00"},      
     { "id": 4, "time": "10:40", "message": "Break" },     
     { "id": 5, "time": "11:00"},      
     { "id": 6, "time": "11:40"},      
     { "id": 7, "time": "12:20", "message": "Lunch" }     
   ],    
  "sessions": 
   [
        { "id": 1, "title": "A great session", "timeId": 2,
          "description": "...", "speaker": "...", "room": "..." }
   ] 
}
```

I don't know what I am missing here but JSON data does not show up as below screenshot.

[image]

Thank you for your input everyone.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? `.live()` was deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9. Unless you're using very old jQuery, you should use `.on()` instead.

Comment: What's showing up instead? Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: @Barmar: I am using jquery mobile 1.0, I know it's old but it comes from a example code of a book that I am reading. Nothing shows up, just blank, and no errors in Javascript console.